# django-review app: pip install error on mac osx

Tags: django, pip

I'm installing [django-review](https://github.com/bitmazk/django-review) on mac osx but it doesn't seem to work.  I've installed other packages and it had worked without any problem.

Here is my terminal command:

```
pip install django-review
```

I couldn't find any useful instructions related to the particular os.  Here is the resulted errors:

```
sh: line 1: 14074 Segmentation fault: 11  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find clang 2> /dev/null

clang: error: unable to find utility "clang", not a developer tool or in PATH

error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 72
```

If you've installed django-review successfully on mac osx, could I get a few pointers on how to do it successfully?  Thank you.

Comment: have you installed xcode command line tools?

Comment: I've installed xcode and command line tools 2 months ago.  By chance, how would I check if that was installed properly?